# Security concern-- prevent root user from editing log files (/var/log/*)

Tags: linux

Just out of curiosity, what if the root user by mistakenly stops/starts any service and tried to remove those traces from the log files and save those log files. Then how can we ensure that our log file is trusted. Is there any way where even the root(superuser) also cant edit/modify the contents of the /var/log/* files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there isn't.  `root` can do everything.

You can limit the rights you hand out to different users in your `sudo` configuration, but that doesn't protect against cases where restricting access is too cumbersome or where [people manage to work around the restrictions anyway](https://blog.qualys.com/vulnerabilities-research/2021/01/26/cve-2021-3156-heap-based-buffer-overflow-in-sudo-baron-samedit).

Log your logs to a different system where your user does not have permissions to tamper with logs.

You can set up `syslogd` to log to a different machine in addition to `/var/log`,
or set up a `cron` job on that other machine to regularly copy the log files over (e.g. by issuing an `rsync` every minute).

My colleagues have set up a [Graylog](https://www.graylog.org/) server and made our Linux and Windows servers send their syslogs, event logs and container logs to it.

Your `root` user can still tamper with the logging mechanism, but once the logs have been sent, they will be safe from them - and, instead, be vulnerable to tampering by whoever has tampering rights on *that* system.

So you can't completely eliminate the problem, but you can shift it around ...

Comment: Actually with SELinux you can prevent root from modifying files inside /var/log. Of course root can disable SELinux on next reboot.

Comment: You can use chattr to make certain files appendable only, but root can also undo this. More useful on FreeBSD, where even root is prevented from doing some things unless in single user mode.

Answer (score 3):

As a historical note, way back in the dark ages, before fast networks and large amounts of storage, we used an analogue, write-once, tamper-evident storage system.  This was a dedicated dot-matrix printer with a box of green-bar fan-fold paper behind a locked door.  The boot sequence of | / - \, interspersed with the backspace character, left some interesting holes on the paper.